# Как сделать горизонтальный скролл на сайте для телефонов

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-web

Мне нужно сделать что бы при свайпе элементы в блоки перемещались. Сам блок состоит из трёх горизонтальных блоков с фотографиями. пример можно найти на странице [Страница с примером](http://ecobalcon.by/index.php/test).
Буду рад если подскажете чистое решение или дадите готовый плагин который поможет решить задачу. Спасибо.

Comment: для телефона лучше всего сделать простой блок с нативным горизонтальным скроллом.

Comment: @zb' можно пожалуйста пару строк на CSS для конкретики?

Comment: `.container{width: 100%} .container.items {display: flex;flex-direction: column;} .item {width: 100px;}`